# Interactively change color of data point in Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, mouse

I am working on Matlab Plot. I have two problems.

1) After plotting, when user selects data point color of that data point should change

2) I need to get the x and y values of that data point

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Data Cursor` in the toolbar.

Comment: How to change color of Marker using Data Cursor

Answer (score 1):

For the first case to get the user input you may try [ginput](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html) And for the second case, if you are showing an image then please use [imtool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imtool.html). It will show you the pixel location as well as pixel value.

Answer (score 0):

The question is 4 years old, but a full answer may be helpful to someone so here it goes...

Plot your data:

```
plot(rand(5,1),'.b','MarkerSize',40) % Large blue dots just to make it clear
hold on
```

Create a datacursor object:

```
dcm_obj = datacursormode(gcf);
```

Set a custom update function to the data cursor:

```
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@dcfun)
```

and then define the function:

```
function txt = dcfun(~,event_obj)
pos = event_obj.Position;
delete(findall(gcf,'Tag','DEL'))
plot(gca,pos(1),pos(2),'.r','Markersize',40,'Tag','DEL')
txt = cell(2,1);
txt{1} = ['x: ',num2str(pos(1))];
txt{2} = ['y: ',num2str(pos(2))];
```

Now just click the data cursor tool in the toolbar, and click on a data point.

[image]